# Google Cal API insert 404 error

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

I've been trying to [insert an event to the user's own calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) in the calendar with the google api but I get back this cryptic error:

```
errors: [{ domain: 'global', reason: 'notFound', message: 'Not Found'}], code: 404, message: 'not Found'}
```

It seems I don't have access to a file, but I'm not sure what file..

Here's the bit of code in the post request

`Google_calendar` is the google_calendar npm module.
`req.user` is the logged in user.

```
var eventBody = {
    'status':'confirmed',
    'summary': "Test summary of event",
    'description': "COME BY AND HAVE A LOT OF FUN DESCRIPTION",
    'start': {
      'dateTime': moment(new Date(1424484000000)).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ"),
      'timeZone': "America/New_York"
    },
    'end': {
      'dateTime': moment(new Date(1424491200000)).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ"),
      'timeZone': "America/New_York"
    },
    'attendees': [
        {
          'email': req.user.googleId.email,
          'responseStatus': 'needsAction'
        }
    ]
  };
  var google_calendar = new googleCal.GoogleCalendar(req.user.googleId.token);
  google_calendar.events.insert(req.user.googleId.id, eventBody, function(err, response){
    console.log("Google response:", err, response);

    if (!err){
      res.send(200, response);
    }
    else {
      res.send(400, err);
    }
  });
```

I've included the access token, the user's ID (grabbed from the google profile returned from oauth), and the email address. I'm still not sure why there's no access (I'm playing around with .edu gmail accounts if that makes any difference...)

Here's my OAUth code with passport.js being used

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: googleAuth.clientID,
  clientSecret: googleAuth.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: googleAuth.callbackURL
}, function(token, params, profile, done){
  process.nextTick(function(){
    User.findOne({'googleId.id': profile.id}, function(err, appUser){
      if (err) return done(err);
      if (appUser){
        console.log("Params",params);
        console.log("Profile", profile);
       appUser.googleId.token = token;
       appUser.lastTime = new Date();
       return done(null, appUser);
     } 

    else 
    {
      var newUser = new User();
      newUser.googleId.id = profile.id;
      newUser.googleId.token = token;
      newUser.googleId.name  = profile.displayName;
      newUser.lastTime = new Date();
      newUser.googleId.email = profile.emails[0].value;
      newUser.save(function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
        return done(null, newUser);
      });
    }
  });
  });
}));
```

Any help is MUCH appreciated!

Comment: I would do a calendar list to get a list back of your authenticated users calendars.  This way you can make sure you have access to said calendar.   are you sure (req.user.googleId.id) is even a calendar id?  also add your OAuth code.  Questions should be able to be tested.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about that part, perhaps I'm grabbing something that's not a calendarId, I'll update it. If so, where do I grab the calendarId?

Comment: Calendar list returns a list of the users calendars https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list

Comment: Oh, it seems I should grab the users calendars and use those for Ids?

Comment: Yes you can only grab public calendars and the calendars owned by a user.  You cant just write to any calendar.